# What about archiving or deprecating significantly old/legacy, software version-dependent questions?

Tags: feature-request, old-questions

There are many related questions to this issue, so I am not trying to rehash the value of something that has been thoroughly debated, but offer a hopefully specific suggestion.

For very specific circumstances, can we archive (i.e. hide) questions relating to usage of very old/legacy software products? 
(*Only this -  not language topics as those will always be needed by someone somewhere*)

What got me wondering was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404171/enable-anti-aliasing-of-code-view-in-xcode).

Nobody but nobody will be using this old version, surely? And there are other, better questions which are more version-agnostic.

Obviously there will be some *delightful eccentrics* out there who will still be using some piece of software despite all rational reasons to the contrary, so I am not saying they be deleted, just merely be removed from the 'cross-pollination' list – i.e. it might show up in a specific Google search, or when searching for an tag relating to the legacy version), but not in the **Similar Questions** boxes.

Perhaps it's as simple as editing the question to add a specific tag (linguistically analogous to `deprecated`, but specific to this concept), and all of those posts are excluded from Similar Questions boxes and they simply fade to the extreme background?

Comment: And who would decide if a question is no longer relevant? I guess we would need a new review queue, gold badge privilege or voting system for this. Sounds like a lot of work for very little effect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068253/edsac-17bit-and-35bit-integers

Comment: @MatthiasBauch I would have gone with the wooly optimists' view that actually a review queue is all that is needed and nothing else, then follow that up with the hand-waving notion that it is "obvious" when such a question is like this. As ridiculous as that does sound out loud, I must confess it is a well-intentioned naïveté on my part of the middle layer that is the review process, because as forbidden as a word like "obvious" is to programmers/engineers, I can't help but feel that it is common sense... Oh,dear. I'm like a baby with just enough knowledge to hurt myself and others, aren't I?

Comment: Could a question be flagged with some kind of "This is a question related to VERSION X" of the software?

Comment: The first thing I do when I read a SO Q/A is look at the date it was posted. If it is 5+ years old, I just take the advice with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deprecated) is definitely not an appropriate use for tags. Such a tag, however named would be a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) which is not really appropriate use of the tagging system.

What you've suggested as described sounds more like a lock/post notice than a tag. The problem with that though is that these are a moderator only feature and moderators are the last people you want deciding if a feature is deprecated or not.

Even if it were somehow extended to allow community driven deprecation I'm not convinced your suggestion adds anything over the existing system of comments, edits and votes. Currently anyone can comment "You should avoid using X in new code and instead prefer Y since X was deprecated in version 1.2". If the community agrees the comment gets upvotes and becomes prominent. Alternatively you can add a better answer (or even [a question you answer yourself](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)) using the newer feature and vote down the old answer that is no longer relevant, over time the newer answer will "bubble up" through voting if the old answer genuinely is no longer relevant.

All in all this sounds like a neat idea for organising all the things very precisely, but the mechanisms needed to do it formally add very little over using the existing tools to do it ad-hoc.

Comment: Yes, a meta tag makes more sense... I suppose I was thinking this would still be an ad-hoc process and nothing more. I just think questions specific to a very old version of a piece of software do seem like pollution and not elucidation. The result would be nothing heavy-handed, just if a question is "meta-tagged" then it is excluded from the set of similar questions that it would otherwise be a member of. But perhaps it really doesn't add enough to be worth the bother. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Though only downvote the answer if you are absolutely sure it's not even useful for legacy-support anymore. You know, today we are creating the legacy-systems of tomorrow, which will be around for the next millenium.

Comment: If you have half an hour, please visit [tag:swift]. It's a good example for why the current approach does not work for deprecating answers (or even questions). "over time the newer answer will "bubble up" through voting if the old answer genuinely is no longer relevant" -- this just does not happen, or very slowly.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that his is a large problem for Stack Overflow: it's signal-noise ratio depends crucially that I get *current* information from a Google search, not that hundredfold-upvoted, then-stellar answer that's been obsolete for years.

A particular fun area is [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) -- the language is new and has been changing violently between versions, and so many answers are just ... antique or even useless today.

Tags are clearly the wrong way to deal with this.

I'd propose a post notice together with a flag. That would allow everybody to state that a post is obsolete/deprecated/outdated; once a post has collected x such flags (I guess 3 <= x <= 5?), it gets a notice that states clearly that the content of the post is outdated. (Maybe notify the author?)