# Deprecated option for answers and questions?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Would it speed up development time for developers looking for solutions if questions and answers were labeled as deprecated? Some answers and questions with high scores are deprecated or replaced with new questions that should get more attention without affecting the points of those that are deprecated.

Right now you have to go through a long list of comments to realize an accepted answer is deprecated.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277666/what-about-archiving-or-deprecating-significantly-old-legacy-software-version-d